# @class May I know the proper use of this

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Anyone can point out a documentation or a detailed discussion using @class.
I've been using this but haven't really fully understood it.
I want to learn more about it and fully understand it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@class` is used to [*declare*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671925/is-there-a-strict-definition-for-the-words-define-declare-and-assign) a class. Essentially telling the compiler: "Hey, there is a class with this name *somewhere* in the source code. The definition will come later, but let me use its name as a pointer type for now."

See also:
[developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1)
[SO: Class vs Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)
[MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-117918.html)

Note: As pointed out by [Richard J. Ross III](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653316/class-may-i-know-the-proper-use-of-this/3653328#3653328), the `@class` keyword allows for circular references (when two classes both depend on each-other) without breaking the build.

Answer (score 4):

```
// header.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class reference;

@interface class
...
@end
// implementation.m
#import "header.h"
#import "reference.h"

@implementation class
...
@end
```

you use this when you have a class that is referenced circularly between multiple files, and you import the header that contains the class described by the `@class` directive, and you can safely refer to the class circularly.

Comment: +1 good point about circular references. That really illustrates the difference between `@class` and `#import`

Comment: That's not what he's talking about. Consider you define two classes, A and B, each having an ivar to one another. You will have to declare one as 'id' or use a forward declaration because of the circular nature, gcc just acts stupidly in such cases. Also I generally recommend not #import'ng files just for class definitions if you do not need access to its members, there's no need—Use `@class` instead.

Comment: @jer: unless I'm completely mistaken, that's exactly what he's talking about. *A* and *B* in your example would be *class* and *reference* in his.

Answer (score 2):

`@class` is used as a forward declaration typically in .h files.  What it does is it says that a class named ClassName actually exists without having to import and read the ClassName.h file since it, mot probably,  will be imported by the .m file