# why is @class used in objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, compiler-directives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@class May I know the proper use of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653316/class-may-i-know-the-proper-use-of-this)

I am wondering why @class is used. I have a general understanding  that it allows you to access things in that class you call, however I don't know the benefit of it..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@class` directive sets up a forward reference to another class. It tells the compiler that the named class exists, so when the compiler gets to, say an `@property` directive line, no additional information is needed, it assumes all is well and plows ahead.

For example, this code would work fine on it's own:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyExampleClass"

@interface CFExampleClass : NSObject <SomeDelegate> {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyExampleClass *example;

@end
```

But, say we want to avoid circularly including these headers (E.G. `CFExampleClass` imports `MyExampleClass` and `MyExampleClass` imports `CFExampleClass`), then we can use `@class` to tell the compiler that `MyExampleClass` exists without any complaints.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MyExampleClass;

@interface CFExampleClass : NSObject <SomeDelegate> {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyExampleClass *example;

@end
```

Comment: ahhhh roger that.. very cool! I should probably go back through my code and change some of my #imports lol :P (I will accept your answer shortly)

Comment: Actually, it's not really necessary unless you have circular references.  It depends on you if the compiler isn't complaining, and it certainly isn't required.

Answer (score 4):

The @class directive exists to avoid creating a circular dependency.

For example, if class A needs to access class B, and class B needs to access class A, then you would need to import class A into B, and B into A.
The linker would go from class A to class B, and then go from B to A, which has that reference, and would do this indefinitely.

Instead, by not importing the class, you avoid this problem.